# ZF2 hydrate object from fieldset

Tags: php, zend-framework

In ZF2, I have a fieldset that looks like this:

```
class PhoneRegistrationFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('phoneRegistration');

        $this
            ->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(false))
            ->setObject(new Phone());

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'name' => 'phoneType',
            'options' => [
                'value_options' => // array of values
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'areaCode',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'label'
            ],
        ]);
        // other fields
    }
}
```

The form:

```
class PhoneRegistrationForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this
            ->setAttribute('method', 'post')
            ->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(false))
            ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'Parties\Form\Fieldsets\PhoneRegistrationFieldset',
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Button',
            'name' => 'submitPhoneButton',
            'attributes' => [
                'type' => 'submit',
        ]);

    }
}
```

I validate the form in the controller. It gets validated, but the `Phone` object doesn't get hydrated during the validation. If I `dump` the object after the validation, all its properties are `NULL`s.

How could I hydrate the object attached to a fieldset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: my solution doesn't work in ZF3.

Accidentally found the solution: I needed to call `bind()` method on the form in the controller like:

```
$this->phoneRegistrationForm->bind(new Phone());
```

It's interesting, but you can throw any object into the `bind()` method, and you still get the object of the fieldset hydrated.

After checking the hydration of the objects attached to other fieldsets, they all get hydrated if the `bind()` method on the form is called. Hope this helps to someone more or less new to ZF2 like me.